# Vertically aling form with bootstrap 4

Tags: bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap 4 beta 2 and I am not able to center a form on the page...

This is the link with my code
https://codepen.io/davidrodri/pen/jawpeJ

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-center h-100 align-middle">
    <div class="align-self-center">
        <form>
          <h2 class="text-center">Benvenuto</h2>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="username">Utente</label>
                <input type="text"  class="form-control"  id="username" >
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control"  id="password" >
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Login</button>
        </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: check my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to set your html and body height to 100% first

```
html, 
body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

then set the container height 100%

```
<div class="container h-100">
  <div class="row justify-content-center h-100 align-middle">
    <div class="align-self-center">
        <form>
          <h2 class="text-center">Benvenuto</h2>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="username">Utente</label>
                <input type="text"  class="form-control"  id="username" >
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control"  id="password" >
           </div>
            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Login</button>
        </form>
    </div>
  </div>
```

now `align-self-center` will get space to fit vertically.

Answer (score 1):

Apply following css to parent div

Updated cdoepen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oowaav

```
.parentdiv{
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    height: 100vh;
}
```